# Не работает css свойство list-style-image. В чем проблема?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.header__logo {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 440px;
}

nav {
    margin: 56px;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 37px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fcac45;
}

.main__welcome {
    background-color: #111;
    padding-top: 139px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 418px;
}

.main__welcome h1 {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: normal;
}

.main__welcome h1 span {
    color: #fcac45;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main__welcome p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #b8b8b8;
    margin: 25px;
}

.main__welcome p span {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.about__us {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: flex;
}
.about__left {
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 104px;
}

.about__right {
    margin-left: 175px;
    margin-top: 130px;
}

.about__right h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fcac45;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.about__right h2 span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.about__right p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 350px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
}

.about__right ul {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.about__right li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #838383;
    font-weight: 400;
    list-style-image: url("img/mark.png");
}

.about__right li span {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
                <div class="header__logo"><p>mycompany</p></div>
                <nav>
                   <div class="topnav">
                       <a href="#">HOME</a>
                       <a href="#">About</a>
                       <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                       <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                       <a href="#">testimonials</a>
                       <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                   </div>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="main__welcome">
                <h1>wELCOME on <span>mycompany</span></h1>
                <p>We are a digital agency with <span>years of experience</span> and with extra <span>extraordinary people</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="about__us">
                    <div class="about__left">
                        <img src="img/about__left.png" alt="mac">
                    </div>
                    <div class="about__right">
                        <h2>Some words <span>about us</span></h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ex quidem maiores ullam quis, at asperiores minus ad eaque maxime possimus.</p>
                        <ul #image>
                            <li><span>Mission</span> - We deliver uniqueness and quality</li>
                            <li><span>Skills</span> - Delivering fast and excellent results</li>
                            <li><span>Clients</span> - Satisfied clients thanks to our experience</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
</body>
```

Comment: ошибочка у вас  `<ul #image>` а надо  `<ul  id="image">`

Comment: И что у вас за #image в теге UL ??? list-style-image установите для  UL а не для LI

Comment: #image я поправил. list-style, на сколько я знаю, можно устанавливать к li, ul, ol, так как действует наследование. Пробовал установить в моем проекте и к LI, и к UL получается один и тот же результат - не отображается.

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, я Вам ответил на вопрос - у Вас неправильный путь к картинке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас очевидно неправильный путь к картинке - вот я просто добавил другую (даже не исправлял Ваш `<ul #image>`), и всё заработало:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.header__logo {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 440px;
}

nav {
    margin: 56px;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 37px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fcac45;
}

.main__welcome {
    background-color: #111;
    padding-top: 139px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 418px;
}

.main__welcome h1 {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: normal;
}

.main__welcome h1 span {
    color: #fcac45;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main__welcome p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #b8b8b8;
    margin: 25px;
}

.main__welcome p span {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.about__us {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: flex;
}
.about__left {
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 104px;
}

.about__right {
    margin-left: 175px;
    margin-top: 130px;
}

.about__right h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fcac45;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.about__right h2 span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.about__right p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 350px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
}

.about__right ul {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.about__right li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #838383;
    font-weight: 400;
    list-style-image: url("https://findicons.com/files/icons/42/basic/48/tick.png");
}

.about__right li span {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
                <div class="header__logo"><p>mycompany</p></div>
                <nav>
                   <div class="topnav">
                       <a href="#">HOME</a>
                       <a href="#">About</a>
                       <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                       <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                       <a href="#">testimonials</a>
                       <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                   </div>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="main__welcome">
                <h1>wELCOME on <span>mycompany</span></h1>
                <p>We are a digital agency with <span>years of experience</span> and with extra <span>extraordinary people</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="about__us">
                    <div class="about__left">
                        <img src="img/about__left.png" alt="mac">
                    </div>
                    <div class="about__right">
                        <h2>Some words <span>about us</span></h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ex quidem maiores ullam quis, at asperiores minus ad eaque maxime possimus.</p>
                        <ul #image>
                            <li><span>Mission</span> - We deliver uniqueness and quality</li>
                            <li><span>Skills</span> - Delivering fast and excellent results</li>
                            <li><span>Clients</span> - Satisfied clients thanks to our experience</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы будете смеяться, но я подставил вашу ссылку на картинку и все равно не отображается. Пробую в хроме и в IE

Comment: ой, установил для LI и заработало. Боже, но мой путь то корректный. я проверил все до запятой...

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, что значит "установил для li"? у Вас же и так изначально для li установлено: .about__right li

Comment: Прошу прощения. В редакторе просто пока ждал ответа экспериментировал и забыл, какой здесь код оставил. В итоге я удостоверился, что код правильный. Путь я проверил несколько раз. Может быть картинку неправильно вытащил из psd макета...Буду разбираться. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, на всякий случай: если у Вас файл css лежит не в корне, а в какой-то отдельной папке, то путь должен начинаться с ../

Comment: Вот это я лоханул...Действительно точки отсутствуют. Я забыл, чтобы вызвать картинку в css, надо "выйти" в корень.Что с меня взять. Это мой первый psd макет. Спасибо Вам огромное! :)

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, если мой ответ помог, примите его, поставив галочку :)